# Multiple databases in Ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have an application which targets multiple databases, it's like an application that watch applications which make reports, mediate notifications, run tasks and stuffs, in a way that is impossible to be controlled statically(in the configuration file), so i thought that it could be done starting a supervisor that supervises multiple `Repo`s just changing its settings in the `opts`(i was thinking in a pool of repos, something like this, sounds crazy, i know), but it's impossible since `Ecto.Repo` has a macro which makes connection bound to the `Repo`'s module, so, there's a way to rewrite the `Ecto.Repo` in a way that i can achieve my needs? I looked at ecto's sources, but i've found no solution digging alone.

I also looked at [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/elixir-ecto/multiple%7Csort:relevance/elixir-ecto/5f2avU3PWyM/-ihiUFAhAzIJ), but there's a possibility that the application will target multiple instances, with different users, different credentials, etc.

I've reached some solutions using `Code.eval` for create Repos on-the-fly, but i don't know how "good" is it, and if it's encouraged.

Answer (score 1):

In case you know all the repositories you need to access I suggest splitting the application in more umbrella apps. Each umbrella app can connect to a different ecto repository.

As a good practice I always extract Ecto and database related code to separate umbrella applications separated by domains. You can see one example in this demo application: https://github.com/silviurosu/elixir-umbrella-ddd.

Answer (score 0):

There's a library called apartmentex for multi tenant support in Phoenix and Ecto https://github.com/Dania02525/apartmentex